# Realm Studio: Unable to open a realm... Invalid top array (ref: 34280, size: 11)

Tags: realm, realm-studio

Realm is working in my react-native app, (running on iPad simulator). I've found the default.realm file but get the error 'Invalid top array' when trying to open it with Realm Studio.  Realm Studio can open the downloaded demo file just fine, but I can't get it to work with my default.realm file for some reason.

I'm a little concerned about the different version numbers.  In my project I'm using:     "realm": "^4.0.0-beta.0"

However, the newest version of Realm Studio I can find is 3.9.0. I would assume Realm Studio should be 4.something too...

Any advice would be appreciated, this is my first project using Realm, so it may be something obvious that is wrong.  I'll gladly provide more info if it could be helpful, but not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue, with same versions as you describe.

In my case, using [Realm Studio 3.9.0 **beta 0**](http://studio-releases.realm.io/v3.9.0-beta.0), helped.

Answer (score 7):

Had this issue with 3.10.0 version.

I think that this issue occurs when you update Realm library version (in my case to 5.0) and still work with the same Realm Studio version (3.10).
So updating Realm Studio to newer version must help.

Interesting thing is that Realm Studio app told me that it was the latest version (3.10) and did not want to update. So I had to manually download the newer one.

Comment: 3.10.1 version as well.  It tells me 3.10.1 is latest version.  When I Chrome debug my react native app, it fails to read any realm schemas using a type data field (Array)

Answer (score 4):

:-) i spent day in this issue thinking something wrong with my code while creating DB.
I think issue was with Realm Studio 3.10.
After updating to Realm Studio Version 3.11.0 (3.11.0.719) Fixed my issue.